# How to add paramater with npm scripts in package.json (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, terminal, package.json

I want to create a file in given folder from terminal using npm script. I know it works like adding custom script in `scripts` object of **package.json** file like:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "addstyle": "touch ./css/stylesheet.css"
},
```

and then run `npm run addstyle` from terminal.

---

But what if I want to pass custom name for my stylesheet from terminal?

I got few options like adding `$variable` in script:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "addstyle": "touch ./css/$filename.css"
},
```

and then add **filename** before the command i.e. `filename=homepage npm run addstyle`

---

Is there anyway, I can append a parameter in the end with - or -- like:
`npm run addstyle --filename=homepage`
. OR
`npm run addstyle -filename homepage`

Comment: What should happen when someone runs `npm run addstyle` without passing the `--filename=...` argument?

Comment: I didn't think about this but it may either throw an error or create file with some default name

Answer (score 0):

Run this command and assign the $FILE_NAME

```
$FILE_NAME = 'homepage' npm run addstyle

"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "addstyle": "touch ./css/$FILE_NAME.css"
}
```

Comment: I know that command, as I shared it but I want a command like `npm run addstyle --filename=homepage`